# How to enable the view of revisions of post in Wordpress Api for custom post type?

Tags: rest-api, revisions

```
{
  "code": "rest_cannot_read",
  "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to view revisions of this post.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/"ID"/revisions (Im using this request)

Comment: Is the request [authenticated](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication)?

Comment: Lets clarify the later comment with a more specific type of authentication: are you logged in? If so, are you sending the X-WP-Nonce in your headers?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a nonce provided by your WP instance, and of course, being authenticated previously (through cookies, set by the wp-login normal process, a JWT, or even Basic authentication). This is because some requests are not approved if they come without the `nonce`, [in order to prevent abuse](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication).

So, you could pass to your script a nonce generated from your backend, the example provided by the linked documentation is straightforward:

```
<?php
wp_localize_script( 'your-custom-id', 'wpApiSettings', array(
    'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
    'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' )
) );
```

Pay attention to the example provided, it is using jQuery, however the API doesn't requires you to use it or even Backbone, in example I'm requesting the revisions of a post with [Mithril](https://mithril.js.org/request.html) like this:

```
m.request('/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1/revisions', {
  headers: {
    'X-WP-Nonce': wpApiSettings.nonce
    }
  })
  .then(revisions => console.log(revisions))
```

Requests without this header, to the default Controllers will respond with a status code of 401.